# Launch plugin on start

Tags: vim

I have just installed the indent guides plugin for vim which is very useful: https://github.com/nathanaelkane/vim-indent-guides

However I'd like to have it launched in startup. The way it works now is the following: I start Vim and then I have to use ig to activate it.

How can I load it automatically?

Many thanks

Comment: This is probably more suited for [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put this in your `vimrc`:

```
augroup IndentGuides
    autocmd!
    autocmd VimEnter * IndentGuidesEnable
augroup END
```